# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; in phpmyadmin SQL Dump --version 4.0.4.1

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
--...' at line 1
```

Here are the first few lines of my SQL file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Dec 13, 2016 at 05:53 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.32
-- PHP Version: 5.4.19

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `adminlogin`
--
```

Comment: I suggest showing us your query

Comment: As iYazee6 said, you'll have to at least send us the first few lines of the SQL file. My guess is that it could start with an improper comment line. There was a bug in a very old phpMyAdmin version (perhaps it came from MySQL itself, I don't recall) where the first comment line wasn't correct (some MySQL versions require a space after the two dashes, `-- ` instead of `--`). You can remove the offending line or add a space after the first two dashes.

Comment: -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Dec 13, 2016 at 05:53 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.32
-- PHP Version: 5.4.19

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `adminlogin`
--

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/34323278/446106, it seems that the .sql file has to start with a blank comment line (`--`).  So if you add that to the start, it will hopefully import OK.

```
--
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
...
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem with the export or import process in phpMyAdmin, but either way, adding `--` at the top fixed it for me.